# update a property of many-to-many

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, hibernate-mapping, hbm

I'm having a many-to-many association between tables *Student* and *Course*, that are connected through *StudentCourse*.
*StudentCourse* has an extra property called *grade*.
In order to have access from a student to his grades for a particular course, I wrote the following mapping in **Student.hbm.xml**:

```
<map name="coursesGrades" table="StudentCourse" lazy="false" cascade="save-update" inverse="true">
    <key column="studentId" />
    <map-key-many-to-many class="Course" column="courseId" />
    <element type="integer" column="grade" />
</map>
```

When fetching the data everything seems to be great. However, when trying to update a grade I get a **unique-constraint violated** exception, because instead of updating the row, hibernate is trying to insert a new row with the same studentId and courseId (which are defined as unique).

So my question is: **how do i make hibernate update the map by studentId and courseId?**

**StudentCourse.hbm.xml** looks like this:

```
<class name="StudentCourse" table="StudentCourse"...>       
        <composite-id name="pk" class="StudentCoursePK">
            <key-many-to-one name="Student" column="studentId"/>
            <key-many-to-one name="Course" column="courseId"/>
        </composite-id>
        <property name="grade" type="integer"/>         
</class>
```

Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: ok, i got it. What i did was fine but there was a problem with the data in my db, StudentCourse actually referenced another column in Student, and not studentId. Fixed it and everything works perferctly.

Anyway, hopes this will help someone...

Comment: ignore the comment. still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Since you set inverse to true for the **coursesGrades** map, it means that **Student** is not the owner of this relationship so it won't update the grades. How do you update your data exactly ? Also I do not understand your **StudentCourse** class mapping, isn't the mapping defined in Student enough to map the StudentCourse table ?